# How to send data to spring boot method using FETCH API

Tags: javascript, ajax, spring, spring-boot

I am exploring fetch api and want to send some for date to a spring boot method, but it is throwing `400` error

JS code

```
let fetchConfig = {
            method : params.method || 'GET',
            body : params.body
        };
        return fetch(_url,fetchConfig).then(function (response) {
            if (!response.ok) {
                throw Error(response.statusText);
            }
            else {
                return response.json();
            }
        }).then(function (data) {
            return data;
        }).catch(function (error) {
            return error;
        })
```

Spring boot method

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/validate",method = RequestMethod.POST,produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public  @ResponseBody ValidateUserModel validateUser(@RequestParam("userName") String userName, @RequestParam("password") String pass){
        System.out.println("--- test");
        ValidateUserModel validateUserModel = new ValidateUserModel();
        validateUserModel.setUserName("Test");
        validateUserModel.setPassWord("Test 2");
        return  validateUserModel;
    }
```

This is how `fetchConfig` looks like

```
body:{userName: "awdaw", password: "awdawd"}
method:"POST"
password:"test"
url:"test"
userName:"awdaw"
__proto__:Object
```

Preview of the values send from java class

```
error:"Bad Request"
exception:"org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException"
message:"Required String parameter 'userName' is not present"
path:"/validate"
status:400
timestamp:1504771336175
```

The error says `Required String parameter 'userName' is not present` but the `fetchConfig` have the required key

Comment: You are sending JSON not request parameters.

Comment: @M.Deinum do i need to change the `validateUser` method signature

Comment: Use `@RequestBody ValidateUserModel` instead of 2 request parameters.

Comment: @M.Deinum but `@ResponseBody` will be still required?

Comment: Depends on what you want if you want to return it as JSON it depends if you have `@Controller` or `@RestController` (in the latter case you can remove it).

Answer (score 0):

Your Java code expects request params, so the expected url should be something like `.../validate?username=<someValue>&password=<otherValue>`, but your js is sending that in the body (which is a better option, sending user and password as part of the URL is not secure at all).

You could change your Java code to something like

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/validate",method = RequestMethod.POST,produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public  @ResponseBody ValidateUserModel validateUser(@RequestBody User user){
    System.out.println("--- test");
    ValidateUserModel validateUserModel = new ValidateUserModel();
    validateUserModel.setUserName(user.getUserName());
    validateUserModel.setPassWord(user.getPassword());
    return validateUserModel;
}
```

Where `User` is just a bean with `password` and `userName` as attributes.

Comment: Even after making this change it is showing 'Required request body is missing: public com.myName.dem.model.ValidateUserModel com.myName.dem.controllers.ValidateUserController.validateUser(myName.dem.model.ValidateUserModel)`

Comment: My model class have only two property userName & password

Comment: Have you set ValidateUserModel as request body parameter? If yes, mind the camelCase notation (password or PassWord?) in both sides

Answer (score 0):

Try Using @RequestBody annotation.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/validate",method = RequestMethod.POST,produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public  @ResponseBody ValidateUserModel validateUser(@RequestBody User user){
    System.out.println("--- test");
    ValidateUserModel validateUserModel = new ValidateUserModel();
    validateUserModel.setUserName(user.getUserName());
    validateUserModel.setPassWord(user.getPassword());
    return validateUserModel;
}
```

and the request should look like:

```
  let data = {userName: "awdaw", password: "awdawd"};
    fetch{ url, {
      body: JSON.stringfy(data)
      method:"POST"
      headers: {
               "Content-Type": "application/json",
           },
     }).then(
            response =>  {
                return response.json();
            }
```